# Extracting Logs

Tags: linux, text-processing

The problem is when I run this command it won't show the complete IP address i.e `137.244.209.141`. What is the way to extract correct this info?

Random logs:

```
2016-08-08 14:24:24 [480879] 1bWgnG-00215x-Li ** sameh@hotmail.com F=<abc@avenir.com> P=<abc@avenir.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mx3.hotmail.com [65.55.33.119]:25 I=[137.244.209.141]:32899 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<abc@avenir.com> SIZE=52485: 550 SC-001 (COL004-MC5F14) Unfortunately, messages from 137.244.209.141 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
2016-08-08 14:24:38 [481047] 1bWgnT-00211m-SS ** microtex@gmail.com (mohsin@microtex.co.uk) <mohsin@microtex.co.uk> F=<production@babylon.com> P=<production@babylon.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp H=mx3.hotmail.com [65.54.188.72]:25 I=[137.244.209.141]:59328 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:256 CV=yes DN="/CN=*.hotmail.com": SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<production@babylon.com> SIZE=19825: 550 SC-001 (BAY004-MC1F33) Unfortunately, messages from 137.244.209.141 weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
```

Command to extract data from logs:

```
sed -nE 's,^([-0-9]{10})[^@]* ([^@]*@[^[:space:]]*)[^=]*F=<([^@]*@[^[:space:]]*)>.*SIZE=[^[:space:]]* (... ..-...) .*([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+).*,\1    \2    \3  \5    \4,p' logs | column -t
```

Output:

```
2016-08-08  sameh@hotmail.com   abc@avenir.com          7.244.209.141  550  SC-001
2016-08-08  microtex@gmail.com  production@babylon.com  7.244.209.141  550  SC-001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that your `.*` that sits in front of your match for an IP address is greedy, so it will match as much as possible in your string.

```
.*([[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+).*,
```

You need to amend the first `.*` to stop at the digit boundary. I would suggest *something* like this may work, but I have tested it only against your sample `exim4` data

```
.*[^[:digit:]]
```

Revised output

```
2016-08-08  sameh@hotmail.com   abc@avenir.com          137.244.209.141  550  SC-001
2016-08-08  microtex@gmail.com  production@babylon.com  137.244.209.141  550  SC-001
```